# What is Eura called in Latin?

Tags: passage-request, finnish, place-names

What is the name of the municipality (small city) [Eura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eura) in Latin?
The name in Finnish and Swedish is Eura and it would be reasonable that the Latin name is the same.
However, I haven't managed to find any Latin sources mentioning the place.

Eura has a long history (especially prehistory), so I do assume that it has been mentioned in Latin texts.
A mention in a dictionary or a list of Latin city names would be good, a passage in a Latin text would be great.

If possible, I would also like to know the related adjective (I'm guessing *Eurensis* or *Euranus*), but my main focus is on the city.

(For the sake of searchability, let me repeat the main question in Finnish: Mikä on Euran kunnan nimi latinaksi? Onko Eura latinaksi Eura?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Vicipaedia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raumoa), which has very little authority in these matters, uses the obvious choice: *Eura.*

After doing a little digging, I found an old work (warning, large PDF file!) on Finnish metal working: [*Historica delineatio officinarum ferrariarum in magno principatu Finnlandia*](http://www.doria.fi/bitstream/handle/10024/111598/Historica_delineatio_officinarum_ferrarium_in_Finlandia.pdf) which includes several references to Eura, including the below:

- pg. 33:

  > Hanc ordine excipit *Officina Cautua*, in provincia *Bioerneburgensi, territorii Satagundensis parte inferiori, & paroecia **Eura**.
- pg. 45:

  > A[nn]o 1694. veniam parandi alterius foci petiit illustris postestor [?], quid vero responsi tulerit ignoramus. 1697 d. 30. Dec. unus hic focus ad officinam Cautua, in paroecia **Eura**, transferendus judicabatur.

Comment: Thanks! I won't load the file on my phone, but I'll take a look later on. Looks convincing. Credibility of Vicipaedia is further reduced by *Eura* not appearing in a dedicated article.