# Deriving adjectives from city names

Tags: adjective, derivation, place-names

One can often derive adjectives from city names, the most famous example probably being *Romanus* from *Roma*.
Such derivatives are typically formed with *-anus* or *-ensis*.
My impression is that *-anus* is typically restricted to names ending in *-a* (like *Roma*), but *-ensis* can be used for any kind of name.
For a first declension example, the adjective derived from *Aboa* ([Turku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turku)) is *Aboensis*, not *Aboanus*.

**Suppose I have a city name ending in *-a*.
Is there any rule or tendency for choosing between *-anus* and *-ensis*?
How do I know which one to pick?**
Does it depend more on the time and location where the derivative is formed or on the type of the city?

This is related to the [recent question about Eura](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4609/79).
I learned that the city is called *Eura* in Latin, but now I would like to know whether to derive *Euranus* or *Eurensis*.
However, instead of this special case I want to focus on general rules (or lack thereof) for such derivations.
If someone knows the answer for Eura, I can make it into a separate question so that particular translation stands out (or you can post it as an answer to the previous Eura question).

Answer (score 7):

This kind of thing is codified in Bennett's New Latin Grammar at http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/bennett.html#sect150

The entries that you seek are:

Names of persons take the suffixes: -*ānus*, -*iānus*, -*īnus*; as, —*Catōniānus*, belonging to Cato; *Plautīnus*, belonging to Plautus.

Names of nations take the suffixes *-icus, -ius;* as ,—*Germānicus*, German; *Thrācius*, Thracian.

Names of places take the suffixes -*ānus*, -*īnus*, -*ēnsis*, -*aeus*, -ius; as,—*Rōmānus*, Roman; *Athēniēnsis*, Athenian; *Amerīnus*, of Ameria; *Smyrnaeus*, of Smyrna; *Corinthius*, Corinthian.

NOTE.— -*ānus* and -*ēnsis*, appended to names of countries, designate something stationed in the country or connected with it, but not indigenous; as,— *bellum Āfricānum*, a war (of Romans with Romans) in Africa; *bellum Hispāniēnse*, a war carried on in Spain. *legiōnes Gallicānae*, (Roman) legions stationed in Gaul.

Comment: So you are telling us that Chilean shouldn't be _chilensis_? Now that's huge. As a Chilean myself I have never heard other forms. Ofc, any Chile-related name in Latin is necessarily modern, yet there are many examples of scientific and Ecclesiastical (and a few civil) names with chilensis on them

Comment: I feel this does not answer the OP's questions completely. Yes -ānus and -ēnsis are appended to place names, but he was asking how to *choose* one or the other. Made me wondering too!

Comment: Many thanks! Although you don't give a comparison of *-anus* and *-ensis* (as @kkm points out), this answer is very useful and interesting, and thus greatly appreciated. +1! (I meant to write this yesterday, but the Finnish midsummer caused some delays.)